# How to securely store data in iOS with React Native?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

If I wanted to create an iOS app that would store sensitive data, how do I go about doing that? Is `AsyncStorage` good enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use keychain to securely store data
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html

Comment: And in the context of React Native?